# save spaces and newlines from textarea flex3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, textarea, flex3

I have a textarea with user type where its text goes to a database.

How can i apply spaces and newlines for user type in the database and display it in an html page after that?

```
mytext.condesnseWhite = false;
```

also

```
mytext.text= mytext.text.replace('&#13','<br/>');
```

Gave no results. Any suggests please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked fine

```
txt.text = txt.text.replace(/\r+/g,'<br/>');
```